# Mysql time datatype returns separate object

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi

So I created .net core web api with entity framework using Mysql as the server. The problem is that when the data type of the column is `time` the result will be different. I cannot change the data type because this is a live server and changing the data type will cause the other system to malfunction.

Here is the sample result:

```
    "lineNo": 164927,
    "empCode": "05-0468",
    "logType": 0,
    "trnDate": "2030-06-29T00:00:00",
    "trnTime": {
        "ticks": 618600000000,
        "days": 0,
        "hours": 17,
        "milliseconds": 0,
        "minutes": 11,
        "seconds": 0,
        "totalDays": 0.7159722222222222,
        "totalHours": 17.183333333333334,
        "totalMilliseconds": 61860000,
        "totalMinutes": 1031,
        "totalSeconds": 61860
    },
    "svrTime": "2030-06-29T17:11:00+08:00",
    "prevTime": {
        "ticks": 0,
        "days": 0,
        "hours": 0,
        "milliseconds": 0,
        "minutes": 0,
        "seconds": 0,
        "totalDays": 0,
        "totalHours": 0,
        "totalMilliseconds": 0,
        "totalMinutes": 0,
        "totalSeconds": 0
    },
    "prevDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
```

As you can see `trnTime` and `prevTime` gives different result where it should be 17:11:00 and 00:00:00. How can I change the result to make it correct?

Here is the table structure:

```
+-------------+-----------+
| column_name | DATA_TYPE |
+-------------+-----------+
| EMPCODE     | varchar   |
| LOGTYPE     | tinyint   |
| TRNDATE     | date      |
| TRNTIME     | time      |
| SVRTIME     | timestamp |
| PREVTIME    | time      |
| PREVDATE    | date      |
| LINENO      | int       |
+-------------+-----------+
```

MysqlContext.cs

```
public partial class MysqlContext : DbContext
{
    public MysqlContext()
    {
    }

    public MysqlContext(DbContextOptions<MysqlContext> options)
       : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Dtr> Dtrs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("server=localhost;database=payroll;uid=root;Pwd=password;port=3306;Convert Zero Datetime=True");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Dtr>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.LineNo);
            entity.Property(e => e.LineNo).HasColumnName("LINENO");

            entity.Property(e => e.EmpCode)
                .HasColumnType("varchar")
                .HasColumnName("EMPCODE")
                .HasMaxLength(15);

            entity.Property(e => e.LogType)
                .HasColumnType("tinyint")
                .HasColumnName("LOGTYPE")
                .HasMaxLength(3);

            entity.Property(e => e.TrnDate)
                .HasColumnType("date")
                .HasColumnName("TRNDATE");

            entity.Property(e => e.TrnTime)
                .HasColumnType("time")
                .HasColumnName("TRNTIME");

            entity.Property(e => e.SvrTime)
                .HasColumnType("timestamp")
                .HasColumnName("SVRTIME")
                .IsRequired();

            entity.Property(e => e.PrevTime)
                .HasColumnType("time")
                .HasColumnName("PREVTIME");

            entity.Property(e => e.PrevDate)
                .HasColumnType("date")
                .HasColumnName("PREVDATE");
        });

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

Dtr.cs

```
[Table("dtr")]
public partial class Dtr
{
    [Key]
    public int LineNo { get; set; }
    public string EmpCode { get; set; }
    public int? LogType { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? TrnDate { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan TrnTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime SvrTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan PrevTime { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? PrevDate { get; set; }
}
```

DtrController.cs

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class DtrController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly MysqlContext _context;

    public DtrController(MysqlContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet("getalldtr")]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Dtr>> getAllDtr()
    {
        return _context.Dtrs.Take(100).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try changing `public TimeSpan TrnTime` to `public DateTime TrnTime` ?

Comment: Yes I already tried it and gives me error: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'Dtr.TrnTime' is of type 'DateTime' which is not supported by the current database provider. Either change the property CLR type, or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.`

Comment: Are you asking how to make it `"trnTime": "17:11:00"` in the example JSON you provided? If so, please show the example code that converts `Dtr` objects to JSON. Most likely, you need to add some kind of Converter that serialises `TimeSpan` as a string, instead of an object with properties.